# GPUImage smudge tool like effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gpuimage

I am looking to achieve an effect in my App similar to the Smudge Tool using user touches and I've seen articles like [this](http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/09/05/how-to-implement-smudge-and-stamp-tools/) on how to implement it, if I port the code to iOS that is.

I've already implemented GPUImage into the App and it works well filtering images. Can the same effect be achieved using the GPUImage library somehow?

Answer (score -1):

I would think, yes. You'd probably want to apply a gaussian blur filter with a fairly small radius to a circular area under the user's finger, and apply it repeatedly along the path of the finger drag.

Blurs are pretty easy to apply as convolution filter, which is taylor-made for the GPU. I suggest searching on "blur convolution filter".

As for how to implement the UI for a smudge tool, you'll have some original work to do.